# CoreMotion delivers data with delay on iOS 10

Tags: ios, iphone, augmented-reality, core-motion

I have recently made an AR application. It is using CoreMotion attitude.rotationMatrix and gravity for determining the camera direction. Motion updates are on a separate OperationQueue with qualityOfService = .userInteractive. UI updates are called on mainQueue.

Here is like the application works on iOS 9.3.5:
https://youtu.be/ecvXa3jXBrY

Here is like the application works on iOS 10.0.1 with exactly the same code:
https://youtu.be/bEKpBWSGawQ

I have tested it on iPhone 5S and iPad 4. One in twenty times the app works correctly on iOS 10.

Do you have any idea how to prevent the data delivery delay from CoreMotion?

Answer (score 2):

Not an real answer, but we have experienced this too and filed a (validated) bug report with Apple:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/52145

Comment: This confirmed bug from Apple has been fixed in iOS 10.1. The problem is not present anymore.